# For loop in bash to replace string in text file

Tags: bash, for-loop, replace

I need to generate new files by modifying a string in an existing file.

I have a text file called newheader.txt, it looks like this:

```
@RG     ID:$FILENAME     SM:$FILENAME
```

I also have a text file called filenames.txt that looks like this:

```
ZF-150-81_S49
ZF-150-82_S55
ZF-150-83_S59
```

I would like to have a for loop to go through filenames.txt one line at a time and replace the $FILENAME string in newheader.txt with the line in filenames.txt and make each of these into a new .txt file with that line in the title.

This would create three output files. For example the first output file would be called ZF-150-81_S49.header.txt and inside it should look like this:

```
@RG     ID:ZF-150-81_S49     SM:ZF-150-81_S49
```

In other words something like:

```
for $FILENAME in filename.txt; do replace $FILENAME in newheader.txt > $FILENAME.header.txt ; done
```

I have done bash for loops but not where it requires replacing a string in a text file. Happy for other solutions such as perl if this makes more sense. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: `sed` is the generic replace command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this... (not tested)

```
$ while read -r f; do sed 's/$FILENAME/'"$f"'/g' header > "$f".header; done < filename.list
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
for f in $(cat filename.txt); do
  sed -e "s/\$FILENAME/${f}/g" newheader.txt >${f}.header.txt
done
```